# Regex to match string ending with % in php

Tags: php, regex

Am I doing this correct?

`preg_match("/%$/",$line,$matches)`

but it wont work!
any help please

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what do you mean? Is an error thrown? Does it just not match what you want it to? What?

Comment: no exception thrown nothing matches!

Comment: Your pattern works as is for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/wpzQ59 returns 1.

Comment: we can't tell you if you're doing something wrong or right until you tell us what you're trying to accomplish. please write better questions

Comment: Maybe there is nothing to match? Is the last character in your input really a percent sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should be right.

http://rubular.com/r/ovrRr2N7Ze

You could also not use regular expressions since this is such a simple case:

```
$string = trim($string);
$matches = $string[strlen($string)-1] == '%';
if($matches) {
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You needn't regexp

```
if($str[strlen($str)-1] == '%')
     //do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Try tossing it into an `if` statement. By default, `preg_match` returns an integer which evaluates to either true or false.

You are not testing the result.

```
if(preg_match('/%$/', $line)){
    echo "Line ends with %\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to match words that end with a percent sign?
`$` matches the end of the input (or line), not the end of a single word.
If you want to match all words ending with a percent sign, use the following regex:

```
preg_match_all('/\b\w+%\b', $input, $matches);
```

`$matches` will then contain all matched words.

Taking the regex apart:

- `\w` matches any *word* character (letters, digits, and underscore)
- `+` matches at least one occurrence ("one or more")
- `\b` matches word boundaries
- `%` is just a percent sign